# How can I avoid a collectAsList() when path is read from another data source?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, collect

I have the parquet path present as a table column, need to then pass this column list as an input to readFrom parquet.

```
List<Row> rows = spark.read.<datasource>.select("path").collectAsList();

List<String> paths =  <convert the rows to string>

spark.read.parquet(paths).
```

The collectAsList is an expensive operation with data being brought to the driver.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Can you tell about the nature of the paths you are choosing. Is there a case, where 5 of 10 files residing in a single Directory are choose and rest is not? What is the use case ?

Comment: @Sanket9394 each path is a different directory. Expecting around 1000 directories to be read.

Comment: If it's only 1000 , it's totally fine to collect as mentioned by Werner. it will hardly be few KBs. I have collected 100k paths and it completes in 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better approach?

No, there is no alternative way.

The code represented by `spark.read.parquet` will always be executed on the driver. The driver will tell individual executors which part of with parquet file the respective executor should load and the executors will load the data. But the coordination which executor should handle which part of a parquet file is the task of the driver. So the paths have to be shipped to the driver.

After the bad news here is the good part: it is true that `collectAsList` is expensive but it is not *that expensive*. `collectAsList` is expensive when dealing with *huge* dataframes. *Huge* in this context means hundereds of millions of rows. I doubt that you are planning to load that many parquet files. As long as the list of paths "only" contains a few ten thousand rows there is nothing wrong with sending this list to the driver. A standard JVM that runs the driver will easily handle such a list.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a CollectionAccumulator.

```
df.javaRDD().forEachPartition{
//executor code
//add values to the accumulator
}

//Note that this is executed in the driver
List<String> paths = accumulator.value
```